# Finding and renaming files

Tags: bash, batch-rename, hp-ux

I have about 1000 files containing the character `*` in the name. I need to find these files and replace the `*` with a `-`. I am working with HP UX v11. I am using the following command

```
find . -type f -name '*\**' -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; mv "$f" "${f//\*/-}"' - '{}' \;
```

I am told it works but for me it renames the complete file to `-` instead of replacing the `*`.

GNU bash, version 2.04.0(1)-release (hppa2.0w-hp-hpux11.00)

Comment: Make sure you're running it under BASH. Also can you check your BASH version on your HP host?

Comment: Thank you I updated the question with the bash version info

Comment: Ok that is pretty old BASH. Can you run `find . -type f -name '*\**'` to see if it lists correct files.

Comment: Yes that lists the correct files. The problem lies with the renaming once found.

Comment: I upgraded to bash 4.2 and the original command works

Comment: oh that's perfect :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command find command:

```
find . -type f -name '*\**' -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; echo mv "$f" `echo "$f"|tr "\*" "-"`' - '{}' \;
```